# Can IMvxViewDispatcher with function to get data from View?

Tags: mvvmcross

For ViewModel to call View functions, we have ChangePresentation, but I would like to get data from view, e.g. Get Current Top View.

Comment: Sorry - I don't understand your example or the question really. Can you edit this question to provide more information. Which platform(s) are you on? What type of object is trying to get the data from the view? What type of data is it trying to get? If you can provide more information, then we can try to help

Comment: I think I get a solution by adding GetCurrentViewModel in my platform Presenter, then in BaseViewModel, directly resolve the presenter to call my function.